# TypeORM OneToMany causes "ReferenceError: Cannot access '<Entity>' before initialization"

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nrwl-nx

I have two entities: **User** and **Habit**. 
A user can create multiple Habits, thus I use a **OneToMany** relation on the User (and **ManyToOne** on the Habit, respectively).

## User Entity

```ts
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { Habit } from "../habits/habits.entity";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Habit, habit => habit.author)
    habits: Habit[];

    @CreateDateColumn()
    dateCreated: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    dateUpdated: Date;

    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,10);
    }

    async comparePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    }

    constructor(props: any) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

## Habit Entity

```ts
import {Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import { User } from "../users/users.entity";

@Entity()
export class Habit {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true})
    description?: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.habits)
    author: User;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    dateCreated: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    dateUpdated: Date;

    constructor(props: Partial<Habit>) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

## Problem

When setting up the above relation I receive the following error

```bash
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
apps\api\src\habits\habits.entity.ts -> apps\api\src\users\users.entity.ts -> apps\api\src\habits\habits.entity.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
apps\api\src\users\users.entity.ts -> apps\api\src\habits\habits.entity.ts -> apps\api\src\users\users.entity.ts


/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "User", function() { return User; });
                                                                                               ^
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'User' before initialization
    at Module.User (...\dist\apps\api\main.js:1782:96)
    at Module../apps/api/src/habits/habits.entity.ts (...\dist\apps\api\webpack:\apps\api\src\habits\habits.entity.ts:42:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (...\dist\apps\api\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../apps/api/src/users/users.entity.ts (...\dist\apps\api\main.js:1790:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (...\dist\apps\api\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../apps/api/src/config/db-config.service.ts (...\dist\apps\api\main.js:1038:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (...\dist\apps\api\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../apps/api/src/config/config.module.ts (...\dist\apps\api\main.js:978:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (...\dist\apps\api\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../apps/api/src/app/app.module.ts (...\dist\apps\api\main.js:147:79)
```

### Note

I use **Nx** and have created a **NestJS** app.
The TypeOrm version is **"^0.2.22"** and the @nestjs/typeorm version is **"^6.2.0"**

My **tsconfig** is as follows:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@awhile/contracts": ["libs/contracts/src/index.ts"],
      "@awhile/ui": ["libs/ui/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

I have tried to use a **ManyToMany** relation and it worked. Also, on a separate NestJS app (without Nx) I cannot reproduce this reference error.
Changing the ECMAScript **target** version in the **tsconfig.json** also did not work.

Both entities are only used in their services and are not instantiated anywhere else.

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by using autoLoadEntities: true when loading the TypeORM config to NestJS. Note that this is a NestJS extra, so if you are using ormconfig.json this property won't be applied.

autoLoadEntities documentation here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities

**UPDATE 04/10/2020**

I kept having the same issue with relations. Another solution I found, even if it breaks some standards is to add all the Entities into 1 file. Export them there and import them where needed.

Keep in mind that the order in which the classes are declared matters.

Comment: This is indeed the case, after reordering my classes error disappeared. This is wrong, it shouldn't depend on the order, as with any javascript code where hoisting works.

Answer (score 39):

Use the `Relation` type wrapper to avoid circular dependency issues, as described [here](https://typeorm.io/#relations-in-esm-projects).

For example:

```js
import {Entity, OneToMany, Relation} from "typeorm";
import {Habit} from "../habits/habits.entity";

@Entity()
export class User {
    ...

    @OneToMany(type => Habit, habit => habit.author)
    habits: Relation<Habit>[];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding `Relation<...>` helped when I moved the project to use ESM modules.

Comment: It works with `OneToOne` as well. Greate!

Answer (score 8):

In tsconfig, setting the target to "esnext" and module to "commonjs" fixed the issue for me

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I tried to get a vue electron app to work with typeorm. Error was: ReferenceError, can not use variable before declaration on an entity. That did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Using this on an auto generated schema. Lots of hand work, but much less than creating the schema from scratch;

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish the same thing as @jdruper by using a barrel file. If you don't have a paths property in your tsconfig.json, add one under `compilerOptions` that looks something like this:

```
"paths": {
   "@entities":["app/src/entities/index.ts"]
}
```

Put all your entity classes in the entities folder, create the index.ts file and add export statements in the index.ts file:

```
export * from './user.entity';
export * from './habit.entity';
```

Make sure the export statements appear in the required order. Your imports would then look like this.

```
import { User, Habit } from '@entities';
```

You can search for *typescript barrel file* for more information on how to work with barrel files.

If you're using NX you can make an entities lib and accomplish the same thing.

It will probably mean having to move all your entity files together and updating the imports in your modules and services. Maybe not exactly ideal, but I would prefer that over having them all in one file.

Comment: How do you make `paths` work with `ts-loader`?

Comment: This ended up working for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had the following code:

```
export class CreateUser {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userName: string
  @IsNotEmpty()
  photoURL: string
  @IsNotEmpty()
  displayName: string
  ...
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreateStreakConfig)
  streakConfig: CreateStreakConfig
}

export class CreateStreakConfig {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  minimumDistance: number
  @IsNotEmpty()
  unitOfDistanceType: typeof STREAK_CONFIG_UNIT_OF_DISTANCE_MILES | typeof STREAK_CONFIG_UNIT_OF_DISTANCE_KILOMETERS
}
```

I'm assuming during NestJs initialization, they instantiate each object in order. So simply switching them solved my issue:

```
export class CreateStreakConfig {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  minimumDistance: number
  @IsNotEmpty()
  unitOfDistanceType: typeof STREAK_CONFIG_UNIT_OF_DISTANCE_MILES | typeof STREAK_CONFIG_UNIT_OF_DISTANCE_KILOMETERS
}

export class CreateUser {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userName: string
  @IsNotEmpty()
  photoURL: string
  @IsNotEmpty()
  displayName: string
  ...
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreateStreakConfig)
  streakConfig: CreateStreakConfig
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you use ESM in your TypeScript project, you should use the Relation wrapper type in relation properties to avoid circular dependency issues.

https://typeorm.io/#relations-in-esm-projects

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35344398)

Answer (score -1):

You should edit like this in the file nest-cli.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "webpack": true
  }
}
```