# ReferenceError with TypeORM Entity and OneToMany

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am getting the following error when attempting to setup a set of TypeORM entities

> file:///C:/Users/.../Projects/my-api/bin/models/entities/entity1.js:29
> __metadata("design:type", Entity2)
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Entity2' before initialization
> at file:///C:/Users/.../Projects/my-api/bin/models/entities/entity1.js:29:31
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
> at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)

This is occurring with the following setup

Nodejs - 14.16.0
TypeORM - 0.2.31
Typescript - 4.2.3
"mssql": "^6.3.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",

This line is related to a ManyToOne decorator on entity1:

@ManyToOne(() => Entity2, (entity2) => entity2.column)

The code transpiles but when running the node command against the resulting js file, I get the error identified.

I tried what was proposed here:
[TypeORM OneToMany causes "ReferenceError: Cannot access '<Entity>' before initialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363353/typeorm-onetomany-causes-referenceerror-cannot-access-entity-before-initia)
but same error.

I have also confirmed all of the entities are registered with the connection.

Edit:
This has to do with the way NodeJS is loading the entities. I tried reorganizing the entity order but it still fails. Is there a way to tell NodeJS to load entities in a specific order?