# How to correctly seed the entities with on-to-many/many-to-one relations with Node.js + TypeORM + Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Although the TypeORM official documentation [gives the answer to this question](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations),
looks like there are some pitfalls. In my case, there are not errors, but looks like the binding has not been executed correctly.

Well, I can't do exactly as in the TypeORM documentation in the code for production, so I have collected the data for diagnostic.

In my case, the `BlogPost` entity depends on `BlogPostCategory`:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne as ManyToOne, Relation } from "typeorm";
import { isUndefined } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


@Entity()
export default class BlogPost {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  public readonly ID!: BlogPost.ID;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false })
  public readonly heading!: string;

  @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
  public readonly HTML!: string;

  /* [ Theory ] About `Relation` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71983552/4818123 */
  @ManyToOne(
    (): typeof BlogPostCategory => BlogPostCategory,
    (blogPostCategory: BlogPostCategory): ReadonlyArray<BlogPost> => blogPostCategory.blogPosts
  )
  public readonly category!: Relation<BlogPostCategory>;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false })
  public readonly metaDescription!: string;

  @Column({ type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false })
  public readonly publishingDateTime__ISO8601!: string;

  public constructor(
    properties?: Readonly<Omit<BlogPost, "ID">>
  ) {

    if (isUndefined(properties)) {
      return;
    }


    this.heading = properties.heading;
    this.HTML = properties.HTML;
    this.category = properties.category;
    this.metaDescription = properties.metaDescription;
    this.publishingDateTime__ISO8601 = properties.publishingDateTime__ISO8601;

  }

}
```

```
@Entity()
@Unique([ "text" ])
export default class BlogPostCategory {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  public readonly ID!: BlogPostCategory.ID;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false })
  public text!: string;

  @OneToMany(
    (): typeof BlogPost => BlogPost,
    (blogPost: BlogPost): BlogPostCategory => blogPost.category
  )
  public blogPosts!: Array<BlogPost>;


  public constructor(properties?: Readonly<Omit<BlogPostCategory, "ID">>) {

    if (isUndefined(properties)) {
      return;
    }


    this.text = properties.text;

  }

}
```

Although I don't know the seeding library compatible with newest version of TypeORM,
in fact, the seeder is the simple script which could be run by `node` or `ts-node`, as in my case.
From the viewpoint of logic, because the `BlogPost` depends on `BlogPostCategory`, it is better to create the instances of `BlogPostCategory` first.

```
import { getArrayElementSatisfiesThePredicateIfSuchElementIsExactlyOne } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

const dataSource: DataSource = new DataSource(/* ... */);

await dataSource.initialize();

// ...

const blogPostCategories: ReadonlyArray<BlogPostCategory> = await dataSource.manager.save(
    Object.
        values(initialBlogPostsCategories).
        map(
          (blogPostCategory): BlogPostCategory => new BlogPostCategory({ text: blogPostCategory.text })
        )
  );
  
console.log("=== CHECKPOINT 1 =========================================================================")
console.log(blogPostCategories);

const blogPosts: Array<BlogPost> = await dataSource.manager.save(
    initialBlogPosts.map(

        (blogPost: Readonly<Omit<BlogPost, "ID">>): BlogPost =>

            new BlogPost({
              ...blogPost,
              category: getArrayElementSatisfiesThePredicateIfSuchElementIsExactlyOne(
                blogPostCategories,
                (blogPostCategory: BlogPostCategory): boolean =>
                      blogPostCategory.text === blogPost.category.text,
                { mustThrowErrorIfElementNotFoundOrMatchesAreMultiple: true }
              )
            })

    )
  );

console.log("=== CHECKPOINT 2 =========================================================================")
console.log(blogPosts)
```

The example of output at `CHECKPOINT 1` :

```
[                                              
  BlogPostCategory {                      
    ID: '1c23cf90-f112-442f-9c12-240d6749d26d',
    text: 'Category 1',                            
    blogPosts: undefined                       
  },                                           
  BlogPostCategory {                      
    ID: 'f433eeb3-22e2-4218-81ed-d3ff21fe4936',
    text: 'Category 2',                          
    blogPosts: undefined                       
  }
]
```

`blogPosts` are still undefined because they has not been created yet.
I suppose, it is fine for now.

The example of output at `CHECKPOINT 2` :

```
[
  BlogPost {
    ID: 'e0403e10-4659-4363-88e7-8e7529823b31',
    heading: 'Post 1',
    HTML: "<h1>Post 1</h1>",
    category: BlogPostCategory {
      ID: 'ae525873-91dc-4b84-92cc-ea31dcd326cb',
      text: 'Category 1',
      blogPosts: undefined
    },
    metaDescription: 'Post 1',
    publishingDateTime__ISO8601: '2024-01-25T07:23:59.840Z'
  },
  BlogPost {
    ID: '5f7dd7de-82c6-4119-8653-288d7e20a79f',
    heading: 'Post 2',
    HTML: "<h2>Post 2</h2>",
    category: BlogPostCategory {
      ID: '1c23cf90-f112-442f-9c12-240d6749d26d',
      text: 'Category 2',
      blogPosts: undefined
    },
    metaDescription: 'Post 2',
    publishingDateTime__ISO8601: '2023-12-31T15:00:00.000Z'
  }
]
```

We have the recursion: `BlogPost` has `BlogPostCateogry` inside, and `BlogPostCateogry` has `BlogPost`s. I am not sure about it is fine, but when I try to retrieve the blog posts from the database, they have empty category. I suppose, the problems begins here.

The database content:

[image]

[image]

I suppose the usage of constructors in the entities is not the cause, because according to TypeORM documentation, the usage of constructors is fine if the constructor parameters are optional.

Comment: How are you retrieving the blog posts from the database? Maybe the problem is there. With TypeORM you have to explicitly specify which relations you want to load, unless you specify the relations as eagerly loaded

Also it looks like you are missing the @Entity decorator on BlogPostCategory entity...

Comment: @pert5432 Thank you for the comment. "How are you retrieving the blog posts from the database?" - by `repository.find();`.  "With TypeORM you have to explicitly specify which relations you want to load" - in TypeORM configuration, I have explicitly specified `entities: [ BlogPost, BlogPostCategory ]`. "Also it looks like you are missing the @Entity decorator on BlogPostCategory entity" - Oh, sorry. It is the mistake during the boiling down of the production code. The real one has the `Entity` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Takeshi as per the documentation of TypeORM ([Check Documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations)), there will be a constraint created on one of the tables (BlogPost) and to load data along with the relations we need to pass extra options to the find query.

Like this

```
const blogCategoriesWithBlogs = await dataSource.manager.find(BlogPostCategory, {
relations: {
  blogPosts: true,
}});
```

With the above query, we can get the blog posts associated with that category.
Hope this helps.